# Creating Deployment object to a service for AKS using kubectl runs throws server reported 400 issue

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, kubectl, azure-aks

While creating a deployment object in object and an associated ReplicaSet object. The ReplicaSet has two Pods, each of which runs the akswebapp application. It throws the below exception.

error: unable to read URL "https://mystorage12111.file.core.windows.net/aksfiles/akswebapp-application.yaml", server reported 400 The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format., status code=400

**Yaml file:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-webapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: load-balancer-example
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: load-balancer-example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: docker-webapp
          image: dockerwebapp
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Can you share related k8s service configuration?

Comment: kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: dockerwebservice
spec:
    selector:
        app: dockerapp
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    type: LoadBalancer

Comment: I see that you've wrongly pointed your service, in fact I didn't find ` app: dockerapp` label in corresponded deployment, even more the container port `8080` does not match any ports in this service. More details read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Why do you come here without any update? If you do not want to get the solution, so what do you come to SO?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, the problem is that the labels' name and value in your deployment and the service. You need to make them the same both in the deployment and service. So the code in the YAML file should be like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-webapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: load-balancer-example
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: load-balancer-example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: docker-webapp
          image: dockerwebapp
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1 
metadata: 
  name: dockerwebservice 
spec: 
  selector: 
    run: load-balancer-example
  ports: 
  - protocol: TCP 
    port: 80 
    targetPort: 80 
  type: LoadBalancer
```